# My form loses focus after button click in c#

Tags: c#, focus, buttonclick

I have a picturebox in my form that I can move around with my arrow keys, but when I click on a button the form loses focus. How do i get the focus back to the form?

I've already tried with `this.focus();` but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the button do that is causing the loss of focus?  The button is on the same form, correct?

Comment: Does the button click activates new form?

Comment: The button turns off the music in the form.

Comment: Post button click code. Else answer will be a guess rather than getting into the problem

Comment: You have to show the code you are using that reproduces this.

Comment: Why is a problem that form doesn't have anymore the focus? Had you enabled KeyPreview to make the form catches the keypress instead of the button.

Comment: `private void stopMusic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sp.Stop();
    this.Focus();
}`

Comment: what is `sp`? `SoundPlayer`? I suspect problem is somewhere else. and you don't need  `this.Focus();`

Comment: yes sp is SoundPlayer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to make the Button loose the focus to the form.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.ActiveControl = null;
    }
```